# Retrieving original size image from Facebook Marketing API

Tags: c#, regex, facebook, uri

So, I am using Facebook's Marketing API to pull some Ads data. Data contains some Image Urls.

For Eg:

https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xaf1/t45.1600-4/s110x80/10156615_6017073002888_1171145694_n.png

i.e. thumbnail size and which is not my requirement. After modifying the url by removing "s110x80" which is actually dimension, from it, I get exactly what I needed.

So, the problem is like how to handle such case in c# and its not necessary that we will get "sXxY" on every requests.

Url might be

https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xpf1/t45.1600-4/10550663_6020611914088_842271416_n.png without any dimensions

```
Attempts:
```

1. I thought of using Regex but not sure whether it will work. as there is not a fixed pattern
2. Using URI to remove second last element but it will fail for url without any dimension.

Just for the sake, I created fiddle for it, If any of you wanna try
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kn2B8H

Comment: second input is expected output. as it does not contain any dimensions in it

Comment: Use `\/s\d+x\d+` regex in your replace pattern. If there's no dimensions there's no matches ergo no replacement.

Comment: use this `@"/[^/]*(?=/[^/]*$)"` regex and then replace the matched chars with an empty string. https://regex101.com/r/aN2nU6/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj, `@"/[^/]*(?=/[^/]*$)"` regex fails, if no dimension is mentioned. For example, the above regex matches the `nodimension` word in the following `url` `https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xaf1/t45.1600-4/nodimension/10156615_6017073002888_1171145694_n.png` which is not the expected output. See the following [url](https://regex101.com/r/aN2nU6/2)

Comment: @KamleshArya, There should be a `fixed pattern` in defining url (for example..to get last section of url, match given word in url, remove trailing slash in url etc.,) for getting proper perfect output.

Comment: @JJJ the only thing what i understood is that..if there is any dimension in the url..then it will be second last element. :(

Comment: @bokibeg..thanks man..your regex is working .:) https://dotnetfiddle.net/EoS5w1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bQcgZN

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string url1 = "https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xaf1/t45.1600-4/s110x80/10156615_6017073002888_1171145694_n.png";
        string url2 = "https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xaf1/t45.1600-4/10156615_6017073002888_1171145694_n.png";

        Regex reg = new Regex("s\\d+x\\d+/");

        Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(url1, ""));
        Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(url2, ""));
    }
}
```